# Unable to delete class due to scheduled job pending, but no scheduled jobs listed

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have classes which I cannot remove because they are in a scheduled job. When I go to Apex Jobs I should be able to see which job they are in, however I cannot find them. There is no Scheduled Apex type in the list of Scheduled Jobs. Is there another method to finding which Scheduled Jobs a class is part of ?

Comment: Clicking "Manage" for each scheduled job shows the "Apex Class" but I presume you have too many for that to be practical? That field isn't offered in the view and isn't in the Winter '14 CronJobDetail so I think you are out of luck.

Comment: It does sound like the same issue to me. Try hitting up support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see a list of scheduled apex jobs go to Setup->Monitoring->Scheduled Jobs.  This list also includes other scheduled jobs, i.e. dashboard/report freshes and analytic snapshots.  You can create a list view to just scheduled Apex.  The Apex Jobs monitoring section will only list @future and batch methods.

Comment: Ralph - thanks for your response. Yes, I have been going into Scheduled Jobs and I can't see any "Scheduled Apex" type of jobs, only report run or dashboard refreshes.Is there any other way a class can be in there?So I'm confused why I'm getting an error preventing me from removing the class in Eclipse because it is part of a scheduled job. It says it's in an Apex Job, and that's correct. I see it when I go into Apex Jobs, but I don't see it anywhere in Scheduled Jobs. Is there a way to remove it from the Apex Job list ?I wouldn't think it would be in there if it's not part of a scheduled job.

Comment: This sounds like a bug SF support need to take a look at for you? Other than that, perhaps try running a query over CronTrigger see if you spot anything in those results. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm

Comment: A while back there was a [bug](http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000STwPAAW) where completed scheduled jobs still prevented deployments.  It's listed as fixed on the known issues lists, but [I've personally run into](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/ghost-schedulable-classes-blocking-deployment?rq=1) after that.  You can contact support to have them run a fix for you.