# Not able to edit in Apex class 'This schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress'

Tags: scheduled-job

Not able to edit in Apex class:

> This schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress

Can we know in someway which scheduled batch job is causing the issue. So that we can abort that scheduled batch job only.

Comment: No way.  
I have the same problem in a new sandbox. But I know each schedulable inside out, so I just know which job to abort.

Comment: Just delete all scheduled jobs? It's a sandbox right?

Comment: Lots of dupes here. One example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/85136/2995

Comment: [Not able to see the class scheduled by a schedulable apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180911/not-able-to-see-the-class-scheduled-by-a-schedulable-apex)