# Deleted scheduled jobs still appearing?

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled

I have a legacy process that has created about 2000 scheduled jobs over 12 months.  They are all appearing in the Scheduled Jobs list in the UI.  However, when I query the CronTriggers object, I see all these jobs have a State = DELETED.

What's the fastest way to get rid of these jobs?  I've tried using Data Loader to delete the CronTrigger records but I get an insufficient permissions error.  I have a case open with Salesforce but haven't heard back yet.

I have found this Known Issues item but I don't want to manually delete all 2000 jobs.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000STwPAAW

thanks
David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right this is related to a known issue, but this has been adressed on SFSE before.  See this question

[Ghost Schedulable Classes Blocking Deployment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/ghost-schedulable-classes-blocking-deployment)

According to @Ralph, a SFSE user with high reputation, he has first hand experience with this and SF support was actually able to fix for him.

> Salesforce support can run a quick fix to address. Contact them and
>   ask to run "fix for locked scheduled class" and include the deployment
>   error message.

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, jobs stick around until a periodic clean up process clears them away.  I believe jobs older than a week get cleared out automatically.  I can't find any documentation for this.

To force a scheduled job to disappear you'll want to use the `System.abortJob` call.  Unfortunately it doesn't have a batch version and each call counts as a DML statement, so it can take a while to clear all of these out.  Just run the following from the developer console until you've got no scheduled jobs left.

```
for(CronTrigger cron : [
  SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE State = 'DELETED'
]) {
  system.abortJob(cron.id);
}
```