# Save process blocked on Sandbox due to ghost scheduled job (which does not exist or is already aborted)

Tags: deployment, job

When I try to edit and save some classes on sandbox, I receive an error "Schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress".

When I go to schedulable job list, I see empty list (no scheduled job).

When I asked salesforce support they replied to me that there is still one scheduled job with State 'ACQUIRED' with null instead CronJobDetail (so, no JobType neither Name).

When I tried to follow their advice and remove that job, I received an error "Job does not exist or is already aborted".

More over, when I try to open Owner\CreatedBy of this job, I see "Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary."

When I query this user by its id (Select Name from User where Id = ...), no results are returned.

Any thoughts how this can be possible at all?

Does that mean that we will have to ask salesforce support to remove this mystical job from all sandboxes each time after refresh?..

Comment: Nothing in `Setup > Apex jobs` too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this previous answer, it's a 'fixed' known issue, but still pops up every now and again.  SF support can easily fix it for you.

Open a case with support ask to run "fix for locked scheduled class" and include the deployment error message.

[Ghost Schedulable Classes Blocking Deployment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/ghost-schedulable-classes-blocking-deployment)

Comment: Do I need to open separate case each time after refresh? Do I need separate case for each sandbox?

Comment: I believe you would for each time you refresh, or you could just reopen and old closed case.  I don't believe you would need one for each sandbox, just make you list the org IDs of all the sandboxes that need the fix.in the details of the case.