# How to delete invisible scheduled sandbox jobs?

Tags: scheduled-job, sandbox-refresh

I refreshed a sandbox recently.  Now I'm trying to deploy something in it.  Several tests are failing with the following message:

> "Job X" is already scheduled for execution.

The problem is that none of the jobs in question show on the scheduled jobs queue.  I've tried to schedule these jobs so the I can see them and delete them, but I get the same message.  How can I get rid of these "invisible" jobs?

The jobs in question were scheduled in production at the time the refresh was done.

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1585. You can try using the code in the answer, or log a case with support.

Comment: Yes, running the code in that answer worked.  I've been able to move on a new (and unrelated) error. :-)  If you'll put your comment in as an answer, I'll accept it.